# How to make the points always on the top level in Graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I often need to append something many times in the first Graphics,

```
g1 = Graphics[{...,Point[..]}, opts]
g2 = Graphics[{g1[[1]], something, Point[..]}, opts]
g3 = Graphics[{g2[[1]], something, Point[..]}, opts]
```

I want Point to always be at the top, the order of other primitives remains unchanged. I know that the Point can be placed at the end in Graphics, it's troublesome to adjust manually each time. I hope there is a smarter way, I made such an attempt, this is a minimalist example

```
Clear[pointOnTop];
pointOnTop[gr_Graphics] :=
  Graphics[{DeleteCases[gr[[1]], _Point, {0, -1}], Cases[gr, _Point, {0, -1}]}, Options@gr];

gr = Graphics[{
    AbsolutePointSize[15],
    Point[{0, 0}],
    {Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Point[{1, 0}]},
    {Green, Point[{0.5, 0.5}]},
    {Line[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}
    }];

{gr, pointOnTop[gr]}
```

[image]

This approach will lose the style of Point. How can I keep the original style, or do you have any other better way?

Comment: I take it, you know about a simple solution like `Show[{gr, Graphics[{ AbsolutePointSize[15],  Green, Point[{0, 0}], Magenta, Point[{0.5, 0.5}]}] }]`. That is, to unify the graphics by `Show` and to place the statements concerning points to the last position under `Show`, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
graphicsPrimitives = Prepend[Point] @ 
  Image`InteractiveDump`$validGraphicsPrimitives;

Multicolumn[graphicsPrimitives, 5, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

Define a post-processing operator `primitiveOnTop` where `primitiveOnTop[prim1, prim2, ..., primk][g]` processes `g` to  put the primitives `prim1,..., primk` in the top `k` layers (in the specified order) while preserving the styling directives associated with all primitives:

```
ClearAll[primitiveOnTop, gPrimitiveQ]

gPrimitiveQ[Alternatives @@ (Blank /@ graphicsPrimitives)] = True;
gPrimitiveQ[_] = False;

primitiveOnTop[prim__ : Point] := Show[#, 
  (p |-> DeleteCases[#, Except[Blank@p, _?gPrimitiveQ], All]) /@ {prim}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
 {gr, primitiveOnTop[] @ gr, primitiveOnTop[Line] @ gr}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
gr2 = Graphics[{Thick, AbsolutePointSize[15], Green, 
    Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2, 1}], 
   {Purple, Point[{1, 1}/2], Red, Disk[]}, 
   Blue, Circle[{2, 0}], 
   Yellow, Polygon[{{2, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, -1}}], 
   {Purple, Arrowheads[Large], {Arrow[{{4, 3/2}, {0, 3/2}, {0, 0}}]}}, 
   Black, {Dashed, {{{Line[{{-1, 0}, {4, 0}}]}}}}},
   ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{gr2, primitiveOnTop[]@gr2, primitiveOnTop[Rectangle, Arrow, Point]@gr2},
  Spacer[20]]
```

[image]